# How to create formated Excel lists from mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, format, export

I use a mySQL database and have to create some lists in Excel format (xlsx). The Excel sheets must be formated. For csv export I use phpExcel (I know, it is obsolete but still working).

Which add on do I need to create formated Excel sheets from my mySQL database. I use php to create the frontend.

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

This is just a copy of the function i use. It just launches the function when a specific $_GET isset. The function creates a xlsx file. If you want to export the file as .csv you can just change the file extension and edit text/xlsm to text/csv

```
   $gg = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM beta_mails ORDER BY created DESC");


    $gg->execute();
            $ggg = $gg->get_result();
            $gg->store_result();

            while ($row = $ggg->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        function getprelaunchCSV(){
            global $data;

        header('Content-Type: text/xlsx; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.xlsx');
        // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        // output the column headings
        fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'EMAIL', 'OPRETTET'));
        foreach ($data as $rowCSV){
            fputcsv($output, [$rowCSV["id"], decrypt($rowCSV["email"]), $rowCSV["created"]]);
        }
        fclose($output);
        die();
    }

    if (isset($_GET["getlist"]) && $_GET["getlist"] == "1") {
        echo getprelaunchcsv();
        header("Location:admin?success=1");
    }
```

Comment: but it's a csv and not xlsx. and I don't see any format information.

Comment: ive edited it so it creates an xlsm instead of csv now

Comment: @Markus just want to let you know that php is backend - html, css, js is frontend

Comment: I know that php is backend. at the end php creates html for the frontend :-)